# Using Java with modules

Tags: java, eclipse, module

I just upgraded to Java 11 and see that when I start a new project in Eclipse it automatically includes a module and `module-info.java` file.  I looked this up briefly and it seemed that I could ignore it, but when I go to import source files, these get automatically added to some package I didn't create.  I rename the package to `default` because this is just a little toy project, and try to remove all the package declarations from all files.  However, I now get the error message at the start of each file "Must declare a named package because this compilation unit is associated to the named module 'exampleMod'" and on the module file, "The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".

On a similar question, the main answer said to clean the project or re-install Eclipse.  Neither fixed the problem for me.

I've also tried adding `package default;` to the top of the source files and that didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: The module-info.java creation is optional - there is a check box to create it on the second page of the New Java Project wizard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of the Java Platform Module System (JPMS) forbids having `.java` files in the default package. But **you don't have to use JPMS**. Just **delete the `module-info.java` file** if you don't want to use JPMS and if you want to put `.java` files into the default package.

When you create a new Java project, you will be asked if you want the file `module-info.java`:

[image]

If you don't want to use JPMS, click *Don't Create*. A non-JPMS project can be converted to a JPMS project by adding a `module-info.java` file: right-click the project folder and choose *Configure > Create module-info.java*.